# Define expectations for public final instance variable

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmock

I'm new at unit testing and am running into an issue with jMock that I can't seem to figure out.  I have a public final instance variable which I need to define an expectation for, but I can't get it to work.  If I make a getter for the variable, it works, but I'd rather not have to create a bunch of getters just to make unit testing work.  Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated.  Here's some code illustraiting what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Main {
    private SimpleObject simpleObject;

    public Main(SimpleObject o){
        this.simpleObject = o;
    }

    public int iDontWork(){
        return simpleObject.myList.size();
    }

    public int iWork(){
        return simpleObject.getMyList().size();
    }
}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class MainTest {
    Mockery context = new Mockery() {{
        setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    }};
    @Mock
    SimpleObject simpleObject;
    private Main main;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        main = new Main(simpleObject);
    }

    @Test
    public void itWorks() {
        context.checking(new Expectations() {{
            oneOf(simpleObject).getMyList(); 
            will(returnValue(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Hey"))));
        }});
        int i = main.iWork();
        assertEquals(1, i);
    }

    @Test
    public void itDoesntWork() {
        context.checking(new Expectations() {{
            oneOf(simpleObject).myList.size(); will(returnValue(1));
        }});
        int i = main.iDontWork();
        assertEquals(1, i);
    }
}
```

SimpleObject:

```
public class SimpleObject {
    public final List<String> myList;

    public SimpleObject(){
        myList = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("Hey"));
    }

    public List<String> getMyList(){
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, where's that public final instance variable you're talking about? I don't see one anywhere. Additionally, it's conventional to create the getters anyway, because lots of automated tooling scans getters to find out what fields an object has. Perhaps look at Groovy, which generates them for you automatically?

Comment: Ah, I think you're talking about on `SimpleObject`. It's convention to have those getters.

Comment: Really?  Some open source projects [disagree](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CodeStyle): "Prefer public final fields to private fields with getters."

Comment: I disagree with the Cassandra team, then. Not having the getter will prevent JavaBeans-based tooling from automatically handling the property. (That said, I'm usually going to use Groovy and not have the boilerplate anyway.)

Comment: Why do you want to mock out the list? It's completely encapsulated by `SimpleObject`, so you can just test the behavior of `SimpleObject` via it's public API. It's extremely rare to need to mock collections classes because their behavior is vast and a function of the data in the collection, so there are no benefits to a mock (and real costs, because you might be making specifications on the collection that aren't realistic)

Comment: Because in my application I have a method which performs different actions based on what's in `SimpleObject.myList`.  `SimpleObject.myList` is actually filled by an API call to a webservice which I don't want to have to deal with.  Simplest thing I can think of would be to mock this list.

Comment: @taylordurden then provide a way that the `SimpleObject` doesn't have to depend on the webservice (perhaps by mocking the web service).

Answer (score 0):

A mock object implements methods of the real object. It does not have fields of the real object (even if these fields are public).

Comment: A mock object implements some part of the public API of the real object. Public fields are part of that public API.